# executeFetchRequest:error A fetch request must have an entity

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am getting error in the search part. when i enter the song name i should get the lyrics there but getting an error says 'executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.' i used the following code

```
-(void)findLyrics
       {
             LyricsAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
                              delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription    
entityForName:@"Lyrics"inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *LyricsObjectEnglish;
LyricsObjectEnglish = [NSEntityDescription      insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"English_Songs"   
                                                inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease]; 

[request setEntity:entityDesc]; 
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(MovieSongName = %@)",song_name.text];
[request setPredicate:pred];
NSManagedObject *matches = nil;
NSError *error;

NSArray *objects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if ([objects count] == 0) 
  {
    //status.text = @"No matches";
  } else {
   matches = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
   song_lyrics.text = [matches valueForKey:@"SongLyrics"];
   song_name.text = [matches valueForKey:@"MovieSongName"];
      // status.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d matches found", [objects count]];
  }
 [request release];
  }
```

Any body please help..

Comment: Are you sure that your entityDesc is not nil?

Comment: its not nil i have added some data into it.

Comment: Set some breakpoints to verify that, eg. after entityDesc creation, after request creation and before fetch request execution.

Comment: am sorry i dont know how to do that

Comment: You should learn. Setting breakpoints -- debugging in general -- is an important part of development.

Comment: but i need a solution for this error :(